# Error when switching beetween mysql to postgresql connection dynamically in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, postgresql

I get this error when trying dynamically switch from mysql to postgresql:

> SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM" LINE 1: SHOW KEYS FROM wb_sales WHERE Key_name LIKE '%unique%';

Error occuring when I'm trying to upsert a record.
I have this code to switch between databases(everything is ok with `$database` variable):

```
DB::purge($connection);

config([
    'database.connections.' . $connection . '.driver' => $database['driver'],
    'database.connections.' . $connection . '.host' => $database['host'],
    'database.connections.' . $connection . '.port' => $database['port'],
    'database.connections.' . $connection . '.database' => $database['database'],
    'database.connections.' . $connection . '.username' => $database['username'],
    'database.connections.' . $connection . '.password' => $database['password'],
]);
$sale = new WbSale(); 
$sale->setConnection($connection);
$sale->upsert($chunk);
```

Also, this code is working when I am switching to different mysql connection.

Comment: Is that error when sending it to mysql or pgsql? You didn't say.

Comment: The code you've shared does not contain any occurence of `SHOW KEYS`. Also, it sounds like PostgreSQL does not support that kind of query

Comment: Error occurring when I trying to upsert on last row  $sale->upsert($chunk);
Is this an error of switching? Can you help me?

Comment: ‘Show keys’ is not valid SQL syntax for PostgreSQL

Comment: @Frank Heikens, I understand that. But what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your switch isn't working correctly, you're executing this query on the wrong database. Could you share the code where you decide what query to execute on what database?

Comment: @Frank Heikens, problem is solved(see my answer below), thank you for participating

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. I discovered that with postgresql you should explicitly specify unique keys in array as second argument, while with mysql laravel can read unique keys from table.
So I just changed last row:

```
$sale->upsert($chunk,['sale_id']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Switching between MySQL and PostgreSQL database connections dynamically in Laravel can be a bit challenging but is possible. Here's a general approach to handle this:

1. **Set Up Database Configurations**:

   In your `config/database.php` file, define two separate database connections, one for MySQL and the other for PostgreSQL. Each connection should have its own set of credentials and configuration.

   ```php
   'connections' => [
       'mysql' => [
           'driver' => 'mysql',
           'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
           'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
           'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
           'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
           // ...
       ],
       'pgsql' => [
           'driver' => 'pgsql',
           'host' => env('PG_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
           'database' => env('PG_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
           'username' => env('PG_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
           'password' => env('PG_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
           // ...
       ],
   ],
   ```
2. **Switching the Connection Dynamically**:

   In your code, you can switch between the two connections dynamically based on your application's requirements. You can use the `DB::connection()` method to change the active database connection.

   ```php
   // To use the MySQL connection
   DB::connection('mysql')->table('table_name')->get();

   // To use the PostgreSQL connection
   DB::connection('pgsql')->table('table_name')->get();
   ```
3. **Environment Variables**:

   In your `.env` file, define the necessary environment variables for both MySQL and PostgreSQL connections.

   ```
   DB_CONNECTION=mysql
   DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
   DB_PORT=3306
   DB_DATABASE=your_mysql_db
   DB_USERNAME=root
   DB_PASSWORD=your_mysql_password

   PG_DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
   PG_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
   PG_DB_PORT=5432
   PG_DB_DATABASE=your_pg_db
   PG_DB_USERNAME=pg_user
   PG_DB_PASSWORD=pg_password
   ```
4. **Dynamic Selection**:

   Depending on your application's logic, you can dynamically choose which database connection to use based on the current request or other conditions.

   ```php
   $connection = $shouldUseMySQL ? 'mysql' : 'pgsql';
   DB::connection($connection)->table('table_name')->get();
   ```

By following these steps, you can seamlessly switch between MySQL and PostgreSQL database connections as needed within your Laravel application. Just ensure that the configuration and credentials for each database are correctly set up, and that you choose the appropriate connection at runtime based on your application's logic.

Comment: Please share more details. How do these steps resolve the given problem?

Comment: we can resolve $connection = $shouldUseMySQL ? 'mysql' : 'pgsql';
DB::connection($connection)->table('table_name')->get();